# Inheritance and imports

Tags: python, inheritance, python-import

This is my first question here in stackoverflow, so if I make one or two mistakes, please, let me now. Also, I'm not an English native speaker, so be prepared for some grammar mistakes as well.

The thing is that I'm a total newbie, and I am learning programming through python and javascript. Right now I've covered the essentials and I'm experimenting with my first app in python, so it's the first time that I practice with modules, inheritance and etc. And I have some doubts regarding the importation of methods/classes through various modules:

1. I write a class (e.g. `Class_1`). Then I write another class (e.g. `Class_2`) in another Module. `Class_2` inherits from `Class_1`. At the same time, I have some methods from yet another Module imported at the `Class_1.__init__` method level. When I write `Class_2`, I have to import again in the `__init__` method the methods imported in `Class_1` or the inheritance implies also the methods imported at the `Class_1` level?

Example:

```
class Class_1(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
    from Module_5.Module_A import method_x
    # Class definition...

class Class_2(Class_1):
    def __init__(self, args):
    from Module_5.Module_A import method_x again?
    # Class definition...
```

2. I have a Module with, say, 10 classes and 30 methods. Imagine that two of my classes need the same method (e.g. `method_x`) from another Module (again, in the `__init__` method of each class). Is there some performance implication for the classes that don't use the `method_x` if I import a method at the Module level, instead of at the class level? What is the 'usual' or the 'more pythonic' way (if there is such a think in this case), importing the method at the module level or at the class level when a) only one class in the module needs the imported method and when b) 1 < [number of classes that need the method] < [small percentage of classes in the Module] need the imported method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually one does not import names within the class' body. The custom is to write import statements near the top of the file

```
from Module_5.Module_A import method_x

class Class_1(object):
    # Class definition...

class Class_2(Class_1):
    # Class definition...
```

There is no significant performance advantage or penalty in doing so.

Comment: Thank you! Only to make it clear... I edited my question. I meant at the "__init__" method of the classes, not at the top of the classes (where I think it would not make much sense).

Comment: The answer is the same for the `__init__` method :) . Of course you are free, sometimes, not to obey the custom. I do it for example to write a self contained function or class...

Comment: @joseincadenza Actually, putting the `import`s inside the `__init__` methods is even worse. Now, instead of performing the import when the class definition is executed it's performed _every_ time a class instance is created. Sure, nothing will actually be loaded from disk once it's already imported, but it's still inefficient.

Comment: @PM2Ring, the overhead is usually meaningless, since, as you say, actual `import` action is always executed once. BTW, using `import` inside `__init__` is the only strategy I know (maybe some other technique exist) to create self contained modules in which the dependencies of the classes can be separated. If `Class_1` requires package `A` and `Class_N` requires package `B`, a global import entails that `A` and `B` *must* be installed into the same virtualenv so as to use either class. If you're developing a wide tool-library, this is not always convenient

Answer (score 0):

As Gribouillis has mentioned it is customary to put all your `import` statements at the start of the file.

You *can* put `import`s inside class or function definitions, but there's no point, it makes the code harder to read, and there is no real benefit in doing so. (In fact, it can be slightly *less* efficient if several of your classes import from the same module, since you're needlessly giving the interpreter more work to do, but it's not a big deal because the interpreter always checks to see if a module is already loaded before it attempts to read it from disk).

One minor exception to this rule is if you have code that only gets run when the file is designed to be both imported as a module and run directly as a command-line script. Such files will normally have a

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

section at the end for code that only gets run when the file is run as a script. And that code may need a module (eg `argparse`) that's not needed by the rest of the code. In that situation it's ok to put such additional imports at the top of that section rather than at the top of the file.

---

Whether you do

```
import Module_5.Module_A
```

or

```
from Module_5.Module_A import method_x
```

the whole of the `Module_5.Module_A` module is imported, the difference is that the first form adds the name `Module_5.Module_A` to your namespace, and the second form adds the name `method_x` to your namespace. Doing `from` imports is ok when you only need a few names from the module, but it makes the code harder to read because you can't tell just by looking at a name where it comes from. So it's generally better to do something like

```
import Module_5.Module_A as m5A
```

and then you can access its names like this:

```
m5A.method_x
```

and that way it's obvious that `method_x` comes from `m5A`.

---

You asked: "When I write `Class_2`, I have to import again the methods imported in `Class_1` or the inheritance implies also the methods imported at the `Class_1 level`?". Yes, you don't need to explicitly import the first module unless you want to directly access its names. Let me illustrate with a simpler example.

Say we have 3 modules.

#### m1.py

```
def f1(x):
    return x
```

#### m2.py

```
import m1

def f2(x):
    return m1.f1(x) * 2
```

#### m3.py

```
import m2

def f3(x):
    return m2.f2(x) * 3

print(f3(1))
```

As you can see, `m3.py` doesn't need to import `m1.py`, unless you want to directly access `m1.f1`, `m2.f2` will be able to find `m1.f1` due to the `import` statement in `m2.py`.

Comment: Ok, I believe that I fully understand how to deal with inheritance and imports. Rule of thumb: inheritances always on top of the module, no performance advantages in make it other way. It's better to import the whole module that to import specific classes/modules. Only exception: code that functions as script and imported module. Thank you very much!